# Javascript setTimeout while disabling input

Tags: javascript

I'm using the function `setTimeout(*function*, 500)` to delay a function being called for 0.5 seconds, but during this time that it is done, I need to disable an input field as well. Can I disable the input by using `document.getElementById("movechoice").disabled = true;` and how do I do it at the same time?

Comment: You want the input field to remain disabled till 0.5 sec or after 0.5 sec?

Comment: Can you post the full code to show more explaine

Answer (score 0):

> As per my understanding of the problem, this might help:

```
       setTimeout(function()
        {
        // your function
        document.getElementById("movechoice").disabled = false; // will get enabled after .5 seconds .if you intended to do do
        }, 500);

        document.getElementById("movechoice").disabled = true; // for .5 seconds (till the time your function is delayed) it will be disabled
```